# How to ignore case in java when asking for user input in a loop

Tags: java, while-loop, ignore-case

I'm trying to run this program as a loop when the user inputs a "Y" value in. I want the input to ignore the case, so that the user can enter "y" or "n" also. Would I use the equalsIgnoreCase() method? And if so, would I want to change my char to a boolean? I'm still very new to java about a month in, so any help would be appreciated. I've been playing around with this for awhile now and I can't figure it out without at least one error.The fact that I got it to loop at all is a miracle at this point :)

```
        char Again = 'Y';
        while(Again == 'Y')
        {
            long product = 1, count = 0;
            System.out.println("This program will generate a table of powers of a number.");
            System.out.println("You just have to tell me what number: \n\n");
            System.out.print("Enter an integer please: ");
            int MyNum = Fred.nextInt();
            while(count<5)
            { product = product * MyNum;
              System.out.print(product + ",");
              count = count + 1;
            }
         System.out.println("\nBye for now.....");
         System.out.print("\n\n\n Try another number (y/n)?");
         String Word = Fred.next();
         Again = Word.charAt(0);
        }
```

Comment: "Would I use the equalsIgnoreCase() method?" - yes. "would I want to change my char to a boolean? " - No, you'd want to change it to a String. Further, Please use Java naming conventions, meaning - only classes/interfaces/enums start with capital letter, variable/methods start with lowercase.

Comment: Can I humbly suggest go back to basics, get the foundations right. Loops, boolean tests, case conversion - these are things to be so practiced in that you do them without thinking. Find some tutorials that are almost too simple for you, and work up from there.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` is one possible solution, but if you're working with a `char` you can also consider [`Character.toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-).

Comment: @wwkudu Is there any tutorials that you would suggest? I am using classes/interfaces/variables that my instructor gave me to use, so I'll take that up with him. I'm still learning so I'm open to any feedback or tutorials that you or anyone else can suggest. I really truly want to get java down and am ready to learn, so what tutorials do you think would help me reach a better understanding of java? I'm currently learning what I do know out of my course book ( java software solutions, by Lewis Loftus).

Comment: There are tons of tutorials - web search is your friend. I like the interactive nature of [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com), but if you have a good text book, then just keep polishing, do exercises over and over if you need to,

Comment: I'll give Code Academy a go and keep breaking in my text book. Thank you! I swear I barely get anything down completely, before we move on to the next topic so I appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` is primitive data type, it doesn't have member functions. So you need to check both the lower case and upper case if you stick with char:

```
 while(Again == 'Y' || Again == 'y')
```

Or, you can declare Again as `String`: `Again = Word.toUpperCase();` then use `while("Y".equals(Again))`

Or, just, `Again = Word;` then `while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(Again))`

Comment: Thank you, my instructor made it seem more difficult than that and had us using different string methods, one including equalsIgnoreCase, so I was really trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Evette22 no problem, you can use either option 2 or option 3 if your instructor requires you to use string methods.

Comment: I love the first option it is much easier, I'll be using that on another program I'm making! I didn't know I could do that. As far as this assignment, I'll be using that last option so I can demonstrate using a string method.  Thank you a ton. I was trying use the method on the String Word = Fred.next(); line.and It definitely wasn't working for me. I'm still learning where I can use methods and placements within my code.

Comment: `char` doesn't have primitive methods of its own, but there are plenty of methods in the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class that are just as good as member functions.  So no, you don't need to convert to a `String` or write two `==` comparisons.

Comment: @ajb yes, Character is a wrapper class for char and it has member functions. But not something similar to equalsIgnoreCase or toUpperCase.

Comment: umm, yes, it has `toUpperCase`